# jquery mobile openlayer search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mobile

hye all, i have problem with jquery mobile openlayer search;

```
$('#searchpage').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
$('#query').bind('change', function(e){
    $('#search_results').empty();
    if ($('#query')[0].value === '') {
        return;
    }
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    // Prevent form send
    e.preventDefault();

    var searchUrl = 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10';
    searchUrl += '&name_startsWith=' + $('#query')[0].value;
    $.getJSON(searchUrl, function(data) {
        $.each(data.geonames, function() {
            var place = this;
            $('<li>')
                .hide()
                .append($('<h2 />', {
                    text: place.name
                }))
                .append($('<p />', {
                    html: '<b>' + place.countryName + '</b> ' + place.fcodeName
                }))
                .appendTo('#search_results')
                .click(function() {
                    $.mobile.changePage('#mappage');
                    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(place.lng, place.lat);
                    map.setCenter(lonlat.transform(gg, sm), 10);
                })
                .show();
        });
        $('#search_results').listview('refresh');
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    });
});

// only listen to the first event triggered
$('#searchpage').die('pageshow', arguments.callee);
});
```

`

my question is,i have json file, but i dont know how to change search URL using my json file.I need some help here.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't really state explicitly, I'm assuming that along with getting search results, you also want to UPDATE your searchUrl with another one that is returned by your JSON file that you will want to use for your next search.

In that case, the simplest way, without massive surgery to your current code, is to lift your searchUrl as a global variable and include a method to update it.

```
var jsonUrl = {
    param: 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10',
    update: function (url) {
        this.param = url;
    }
};
```

Change this:

```
var searchUrl = 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10';
searchUrl += '&name_startsWith=' + $('#query')[0].value;
```

To this:

```
var searchUrl = jsonUrl.param + '&name_startsWith=' + $('#query')[0].value;
```

Assuming that your new json url is in contained (your_json_object).url, add one line before the $.getJSON closure:

```
jsonURL.update(data.url);
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
var jsonUrl = {
    param: 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10',
    update: function (url) {
        this.param = url;
    }
};

$('#searchpage').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
$('#query').bind('change', function(e){
$('#search_results').empty();
if ($('#query')[0].value === '') {
    return;
}
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

// Prevent form send
e.preventDefault();

var searchUrl = jsonUrl.param + '&name_startsWith=' + $('#query')[0].value;
$.getJSON(searchUrl, function(data) {
    $.each(data.geonames, function() {
        var place = this;
        $('<li>')
            .hide()
            .append($('<h2 />', {
                text: place.name
            }))
            .append($('<p />', {
                html: '<b>' + place.countryName + '</b> ' + place.fcodeName
            }))
            .appendTo('#search_results')
            .click(function() {
                $.mobile.changePage('#mappage');
                var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(place.lng, place.lat);
                map.setCenter(lonlat.transform(gg, sm), 10);
            })
            .show();
    });
    $('#search_results').listview('refresh');
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
});

// only listen to the first event triggered
$('#searchpage').die('pageshow', arguments.callee);

//add this to update new URL retrieved into your jsonUrl object.
jsonURL.update(data.url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i just change the jsonURL into this, 
var jsonUrl = {
    param: 'test.json',
    update: function (url) {
        this.param = url;
    }
};
is it right?

Comment: the "param" variable should be the url that you are getting data from. Given the context of your question it would have been "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10" as what I have written above.

Comment: i edited my answer above to include a complete code at the end.

Comment: please accept the answer it if is what you need. thanks.

Comment: thanks for the info, how i want to change and using my own json file instead using the  "ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10";
i have json file name test.json

Comment: im using your code given, by have error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonURL is not defined'

Comment: your question was rather unclear. ignore my answer. just change this line:
`var searchUrl = "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10";`

to the url that points to your test.json file.

next time please be more clear if you want to get help.

Comment: thanks for reply, you give me code that need to put at before the $.getJSON closure, the code are 'jsonURL.update(data.url);' but have error appear 
'Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonURL is not defined' need your help is it i need to define the jsonURL?

Comment: ignore my answer TOTALLY. just change this line: var searchUrl = "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10";

Comment: thanks for your response, i already change var searchUrl= 'http://localhost:85/learnOpenLayer/test.json', but have error,

GET http://localhost:85/learnOpenLayer/test.json&negeri=08 404 (Not Found), how i want to intergrate my test.json file with this application